# Why does android not fall with the error "CalledFromWrongThreadException"?

Tags: android, multithreading

When I run a code below, application does not fall:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    final Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    new Mt(b).start();

}
```

And this code falls (when i click on the button1 with error "CalledFromWrongThreadException"):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    final Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new Mt(b).start();
            }
        });

}
```

Where Mt class is

```
class Mt extends Thread{
    Button b;
    Mt(Button b){
        this.b=b;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        b.setText("4");
    }
}
```

Why the first example does not fall with error "CalledFromWrongThreadException" ?

Answer (score 0):

Thread will run in non UI Thread. UI related operations must be done in UI thread.. Modify the code in thread.run() method

```
public void run() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           b.setText("4");  
       }
   });

}
```

Comment: So why does the first example work?

Comment: Because you are changing the text of the button in OnClick. Until unless you click on the button, thread will not start.

Comment: Still, both should fail. The access to the button happens on a separate thread regardless.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hunch, but the first example does not fail because there is no UI during the execution of `onCreate`. The check for thread access does not occur in the `setText` method until it actually plans on changing something that is visible to the user. Since nothing is being drawn to the screen yet, there is no problem.